# Sublime Text: Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages\User\SublimeLinter.sublime-settings:1:1

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm getting the following error in Sublime Text 3:

Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages\User\SublimeLinter.sublime-settings:1:1

I've tried removing the package and that makes the error go away. I thought I'd reinstall the package and have a fresh start but that brought the error back. Has anyone experienced this?

[image]

Comment: The file mentioned in your `User` package is broken at line 1, column 1 (that's what the `:1:1` means); that file remains in your User folder whether the package is there or not. Use `Preferences > Browse Packages` to find your `User` package, then either fix the file or delete it.

Comment: I had this problem for ages. It took me awhile to investigate. Then I found that I symlinked the preferences file to my dropbox which used to work great. But dropbox changed their settings so files aren't downloaded locally by default anymore and it was essentially pointing at a fake dropbox file.